# How to get a reference to an existing actor from a non-actor in Akka?

Tags: scala, akka, actor

In my application, I have a class which needs to communicate with an existing actor already created in an actorSystem. How do I get a reference to that actor from this non-actor class?

Answer (score 0):

If you have the reference to the actor system (https://doc.akka.io/api/akka/current/akka/actor/ActorSystem.html), then you can simply invoke `actorSelection` with the path of the actor. This will give you an `ActorSelection`, on which you can call `resolveOne`, and then wait until you get the reference of the actor. Once you have the actor reference, you can send messages to it.

Here is more information about addressing actors: https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/general/addressing.html .

Comment: I am unable to get the reference to the actor system. How do I get that? Is there an API to get the actor system? Although I have the full path to the actor itself but using that in actor selection isn't working. Ex:akka://squbs/user/myapp/loaderactor/ doesn't work.

Comment: It gives an error: akka.actor.ActorNotFound: Actor not found for: ActorSelection[Anchor(akka://squbs/), Path(/user/myapp/*)]

Comment: 1) How did you instantiate you actors in the first place? Isn't there something like `myActorSystem.actorOf(propsBlahBlahBlah)` in you code? Then `myActorSystem` is the thing that you want. 
2) Every actor must have <em>some</em> path pointing to it. If you didn't get the actor, then the path was wrong, or you asked the wrong actor system.

Comment: So, my application is built on top of a framework named "squbs" which according to the doc is the name of the ActorSystem using which the actor is created. I am using the correct path as well. In here 
 - **akka://squbs/user/myapp/loaderactor/**, the part before user is the actorSystem which I got from printing the actor Path.

Comment: How exactly did you print the actor path? Is this the output produced by the actor itself? If this is not the case, then how do you know that this is "the correct path" -- if it were correct, you would get the desired actorRef, wouldn't you?

Comment: I printed this in the actor: self.path and got the output.

Comment: Ok, good... Are you sure that the actor is not in some remote actor system, that it shouldn't be accessed over `akka.tcp` for example? Are you sure that the actor isn't dead by the time you are trying to retrieve it's actorRef? Otherwise, I don't know what's going on, consider trying to isolate the problem and come up with a minimal compilable / runnable example. Or, alternatively, add the `squbs` tag to your question, maybe it helps to attract someone who knows more about that system.

Comment: I don't think so. From what I get in the framework docs and from the output of printing the path, i am using the correct actor system.  So, If I have to get a reference to an existing actorSystem, how do I go about it? I could not find anything in the documentation